# Direct-speech alternative quotation in Italian

Tags: quoting, csquotes, quotation

I am currently using `quotmark` with guillemots (standard Italian), but I would like to switch to "alternate" way to represent direct speech, which is (IMHO) much nicer.

- direct speech starts with `em-dash`.
- *if* direct speech is the full paragraph then there is *no* closing quotes (Joyce style).
- *if* there is a trailing non-direct-speech in paragraph (e.g.: "No", said Tom.) then a closing em-dash is required.
- inner (recursive) direct-speech should be represented by inverted quotes (something like: --- Tom said "no", but seemed unconvinced --- commented Ted.)

These are the general rules for Italian "alternate", I also need to represent some special speech which I currently render using "maiuscoletto" (`\scshape`), but result is not completely satisfactory when combined with other effects (e.g.: `\tqt{\scshape Esatto. Sono \begin{bfseries}IO\end{bfseries} che mando avanti la selezione naturale. Se \begin{bfseries}IO\end{bfseries} non collaboro la selezione si ferma, per un po' languisce e poi \begin{itshape}torna indietro\end{itshape}!}`) as setting other fonts apparently clears "maiuscoletto".

Is there some package implementing something like the above?
I was not able to find anything comparable (without extensive rewriting).

Comment: Why `\begin{bfseries}IO\end{bfseries}` instead of the simpler (and more correct) `\textbf{IO}`? Anyway, the problem is simply that the standard Computer Modern fonts lack smallcaps in boldface and italics.

Comment: @egreg: why? Simply because that's the first thing I found. I'm *not* an expert in text formatting, latex or otherwise, I'm just trying to publish a novel in the best possible way (hell! I'm actually not even a writer! I work in a completely different line, but I would like to do things in a "proper"way... as much as I can). Thanks for the hint. Should I switch font? If so: what would You suggest?